# FirebaseUI documentation

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have seen the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` in the Firebase sample. But every time I tried to look up documents about it, the Firebase Reference had nothing to do with it.

All I can see is the contents in GitHub. Why are there no references to this in the Firebase Homepage Reference?

Could I see the official documentation on this? FirebaseUI documents such as `firebase.ui.database`.

In addition, if there are other documents that are not on Firebase's official homepage, where can I find out and study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FirebaseUI packages](https://opensource.google.com/projects/firebaseui) are developed separately from the main Firebase SDK. Therefore the documentation for these packages can be found on the [Firebase UI repository](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui) instead.

For example, the documentation for the Android flavour of the FirebaseUI Database package can be found on the [`firebase/FirebaseUI-Android` GitHub repository](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).

Comment: Thanks. In addition, if there are other documents that are not on Firebase's official homepage, where can I find out and study?

Comment: Most of the libraries used in the official documentation are linked to the correct documentation pages. The [Google Cloud Platform documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/) is also a useful resource for a number of features that crossover.